# Python - generate variable list comprehension expression based on input

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

New here and new to Python, so please be gentle

I'm trying to define a function to generate different list comprehension expressions based on input. What I want to happen:

input:

```
TableTop = Part(L,D,T)
```

generate:

```
TableTop.unique = [(L,D,T) for L in lengthList for D in depthlist, for T in thickList]
```

or input:

```
LegPost = Part(H,T)
```

generate:

```
LegPost.unique = [(H,T) for H in heightList for T in thickList]
```

EDIT

Sorry guys, let's try this again.

Context:

I am trying to write a program to take in a list of Parts (in this case parts of a kitchen table) and a list of Dimensions (options for customizing dimensions of the table), and output Blender mesh objects. This particular table has 9 Parts and 5 Dimensions

```
partList = (TableTop, LegPost, BaseFoot, AngleBrace, CenterAngle, TopCap, HorizontalBrace, VerticalBrace, CenterBrace)

dimList = (lengthList, depthList, heightList, thickList, ohangList)

lengthList = range(60,145)   # table length options (60"-144")
depthList = range(30,55)     # table depth options (30"-54")
heightList = range(30,45)    # table height options (30"-44")
thickList = range(3,9)       # tabletop thickness options (3/4"-2")
ohangList = range(10,23)     # table end overhang options (10"-22")
```

Not every Part of the table is affected by every Dimension. I want to create one Blender mesh for each *unique* table part (e.g. # of unique LegPosts = `len(heightList) * len(thickList)` = 84). To do this, I have created a class Part:

```
class Part:  
    def __init__(self, dims):  
        self.dims = dims
        ...
```

I want to define this class as abstractly as possible, so that it can be used for other pieces and types of furniture later.

Where I'm Stuck:

I want to define a function within the class that runs at instantiation, takes a tuple (e.g. (L,D,T)), and generates a list comprehension (e.g. [(L,D,T) for L in lengthList for D in depthlist, for T in thickList]) where L, D, H, T, and G always correspond to lengthList, depthList, heightList, thickList, and ohangList respectively. I have no idea how to create this function, just looking for a little direction.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is not clear. By "generate different list comprehension expressions" do you mean that you want to get the *result* of the comprehensions you show, or you want a string that contains the comprehension just as you show it, or something else? How is the function to know about `lengthList` and `depthList` and `thickList`? Etc. It would help if you show us a *complete* example that shows what you want--include the input and desired output. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Part:  
    def __init__(self, *dims):  
        self.dims = *dims
        ...
```

Once `self.dims` has unpacked the `*dims`, it is possible to do a `for` loop over it to do what you require. To do what you require, you would require using recursion to generate n-level nested `for` loops

```
def gen_nestedforloop(dims): #throw in self.dims here
    output = []
    if len(dims) > 1:
        gen_nestedforloop(dims[1:])
    else:
        output.append([x for x in dims])
        return output
```

Comment: The *args notation helps a little, but I'm still not sure how to get a list of ordered tuples from the n-level nested `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

That's why `itertools.product` exists:

```
import itertools

L = range(60,145)   # table length options (60"-144")
D = range(30,55)     # table depth options (30"-54")
H = range(30,45)    # table height options (30"-44")
T = range(3,9)       # tabletop thickness options (3/4"-2")
O = range(10,23)     # table end overhang options (10"-22")

class Part:
    def __init__(self, dims):
        self._dims = dims

    @property
    def unique(self):
        return list(itertools.product(*self._dims))

>>> Part((T,H)).unique
[(3, 30), (3, 31), (3, 32), (3, 33), (3, 34), ..., (8, 39), (8, 40), (8, 41), (8, 42), (8, 43), (8, 44)]
```

If you want to create your own implementation, you should use a recursive function:

```
>>> def cprod(*dims):
...     if len(dims) == 0: return []
...     if len(dims) == 1: return list(dims[0])
...     def cprod_aux(d, *ds):
...         return [(x, *y) for x in d for y in cprod_aux(*ds)] if ds else ((x,) for x in d)
...     return cprod_aux(*dims)
>>> cprod()
[]
>>> cprod(D)
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
>>> cprod(L, D, H)
[(60, 30, 30), (60, 30, 31), (60, 30, 32), (60, 30, 33), (60, 30, 34), (60, 30, 35), ..., (144, 54, 39), (144, 54, 40), (144, 54, 41), (144, 54, 42), (144, 54, 43), (144, 54, 44)]
```

The implementation is naive (you could use some [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization))